# If $R\to S$ is a ring homorphism with $J$ an ideal of $S$. Show that the preimage of $J$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\alpha\colon R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $J$ be an ideal of $S$, and define the preimage of $J$ by $\alpha^{−1}(J)=\{r\in R\mid \alpha(r)\in J\}$. Show that $\alpha^{-1}(J)$ is an ideal of $R$. I have already shown why it is an additive subgroup of $R$, but am having a little trouble with the 'project absorption' property.

Comment: If $f(a)\in J$ and $r\in R$ then $f(ra)=f(r)f(a)\in f(r)J\subseteq J$. All you have to do is write things down!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @anon: All you have to do is using comment boxes for comments and answers for answers!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\alpha : R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $J$ be an ideal of $S$.

Define $I := \alpha^{-1}(J) = \{r \in R : \alpha(r) \in J \}$.

You've already shown that it's an additive subgroup: Let $i, i' \in I$,

- Then $\alpha(i), \alpha(i') \in J$ and thus $\alpha(i + i') = \alpha(i) + \alpha(i') \in J$ since $J$ being an ideal is an additive group.
- Ring homomorphisms map zero to zero, so $\alpha(0_R) = 0_S \in J$, so $0_R \in I$ with $0_R + i = i + 0_R = i$ which means $I$ contains an additive identity.
- since $\alpha(i) \in J$, $\alpha(-i) = \alpha(-1) \alpha(i) \in J$ by the absorption property of $J$, so $-i \in I$ which means $I$ contains additive inverses.

For absorption: Let $r \in R, i \in I$ which means $\alpha(i) \in J$.

- Observe that $\alpha(ri) = \alpha(r) \alpha (i) \in J$ since $J$ is an ideal and $\alpha(i) \in J$, so it will absorb $\alpha(r)$.
- That $\alpha(ir) \in J$ follows from the same reasoning as above, assuming $J$ is a two-sided ideal.